# change textview style in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to change the style of textview of group and child item  in ExpandableListView , but it doesn't work .

in the creating adapter first text view will be (lblListHeader ) and second will be (lblListItem )

```
mAdapter = new HadithExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_ahadith, R.layout.drawer_list_ahadith,
                new String[] { "ChapterName" },
                new int[] { R.id.lblListHeader }, new String[] { "HadithTitel" },
                new int[] { R.id.lblListItem });
```

in the layout this is file which contain two textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: both `lblListItem` and `lblListHeader` has the same attributes in the layout. so they will look the same!

Comment: this not the problem , two items doesn't appear